# Angular resolve new problem InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, typescript

These error always appear when I load data from the server.

It is old code from other person and I want to do the best code here.

¿Can anybody apport the best way to do that and comment if there are any code patters to do that correctly and improve the code to be as faster as possible?

**ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class EmployeePortalService implements Resolve<any>{

  
     areas:  any[]
     organs:  any[]
     units:  any[]
     selectedArea:  any
     selectedOrgan: any


    constructor(
     private http: HttpClient
    ) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any>    | any {
     return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      Promise.all([this.loadAll()]).then((response: any) => {
        resolve(response)
      }, reject)
    })
  }
  

   loadAll(): Promise<any>{
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this.http.get("/api/getWorkAreas").subscribe((response: any) => {
         this.areas = response
         resolve(response)
      }, reject) 
    })
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: Too much bad code here. Do not wrap observable into promise in Angular, do not subscribe and extract data from observer (here you can use `tap` operator if you really need this extract or use `shareReplay`). The content of resolve will be `return this.http.get('/api/getWorkAreas').pipe(tap(response => this.areas = response;));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I discover that my fault was an async pipe that is not needed in the templeate code